# Showing Invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int')

Tags: c, structure

```
 struct MinHeap{
int size;
int* array;
 };

 void minHeapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int idx)
 {
int smallest, left, right;
smallest = idx;
left = 2 * idx + 1;
right = 2 * idx + 2;

if (left < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[left]->key < minHeap-
>array[smallest]->key )
  smallest = left;

if (right < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[right]->key < minHeap-
>array[smallest]->key )
  smallest = right;

if (smallest != idx)
{
    // The nodes to be swapped in min heap
    MinHeapNode *smallestNode = minHeap->array[smallest];
    MinHeapNode *idxNode = minHeap->array[idx];

    // Swap positions
    minHeap->pos[smallestNode->v] = idx;
    minHeap->pos[idxNode->v] = smallest;

    // Swap nodes
    swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[idx]);

    minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
}
}
```

It shows Invalid type argument of '->' (have 'int') in the minheapify function wherever '->' is used. Please tell me what to do here because the other functions are working well.

Comment: The compiler tells you [exactly what is wrong](https://godbolt.org/g/KkuBuQ). it highlights the `->key` and says `Base operand of '->' is not a pointer.` Because `minHeap->array[left]` is not a pointer.

Comment: where are you getting `key` from? Are you mixing C++ with some other language?

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
minHeap->array[left]->key
```

of which `minHeap` is of type pointer to `struct MinHeap`.
Therefor `minheap->`accesses a member of the `structMinHeap`.
Because of `minHeap->array`, the accessed member is `array` which is of type pointer to `int`.
With the `[left]` you treat that pointer like an array, which is OK. The result is an `int`.
So what you are applying the next `->` to should be a pointer, but is an `int`.

This is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve. What makes you think that an int contains a struct member named "key" ? This question should demonstrate that the problems are probably too complex to answer here. What might help you is https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

1. `minHeap->array[left]` is integer value(not a pointer to a structure), so `minHeap->array[left]->key` produces compilation error.
2. `MinHeapNode *smallestNode = minHeap->array[smallest];` transforms `int` into MinHeapNode*, which is probably not an `int`